# print interactive graph (girafe object) inside loop in rmarkdown

Tags: loops, plot, printing, r-markdown, interactive

I have a list of girafe objects, created using `girafe()` from the package `ggiraph`. These are essentially interactive ggplot objects.

I would like to loop over the list of girafe objects and print these plots in an rmarkdown file.

Using results = "asis" in the code chunk, my attempts have been along the lines of:

```
if ("chart.ls" %in% names(current)) {
 for (i in seq_along(current$chart.ls)){
  knitr::knit_print(current$chart.ls[[i]])
 }
}
```

Further, the below code will print the plot as expected

```
if ("chart.ls" %in% names(current)) {
 knitr::knit_print(current$chart.ls[[2]])
}
```

I understand there are alternative ways to print graphs from inside a loop, but these methods don't seem to work for interactive graphs.

Is there a way to print girafe objects from inside a loop, without using external packages? (e.g. `knitrContainer`)

I have a workaround, which is to use child Rmds. Where I can loop over the object, then reference a child.rmd which then prints it. But hoping for a real solution.